# binding to items self (this) for a button in a itemtemplate/datatemplate?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've found similar examples for this but nothing that solves my exact issue :(

I'm using silverlight on Phone7, and I have a itemslist that I bind a List to the ItemsSource.

In my dataTemplate, I have a button, and what I really want to do is set the button.tag property to give me back the original instance of the myClass object that is bound to that template.

I cant seem to figure out how in the xaml binding, to specify a binding to the object instance for that template. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone that needs it in the future -
What you need is

```
Tag="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"
```

That will bind to the source of that itemtemplate